# How do I match a certain string that does not contain an asterisk?

Tags: regex, perl, regex-lookarounds

I have a regex that captures a keyword that comes after a number sign:

```
/^#\s*([a-zA-Z\-\s]+)/
```

However, I need to change the regex to specify to *not* match a string that contains an asterisk. For instance, I need the regex to match `# keyword`, but *not* `# *keyword`.

The following is my best attempt at solving this:

```
/^#\s[^[*]]*([a-zA-Z\-\s]+)/
```

I'm brand new to Perl so I'm sure the solution is very simple, but my time spent researching and trial and error didn't help me a whole lot.

Comment: Will the asterisk always be at the beginning of the keyword?

Comment: Luke, it will always be at the beginning.

Comment: Dan, for some reason my second regex messes up my keyword capture.

Comment: Sorry my earlier comment was wrong. My question is this - why do you say `\s` again inside the part that's supposed to match the keyword?

Comment: @DavidWright: As Dan says, `/^#\s*([a-zA-Z\-\s]+)/` does not match `# *keyword`. If you have reason to believe otherwise, please post enough information that we can show you what's really going on. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming I'm understanding correctly, your first regex is fine.  As it is a whitelist and the asterisk character isn't in there, it won't match a keyword containing an asterisk character:

```
/^#\s*([a-zA-Z\-\s]+)/
```

This will still match for something like:

```
# key*word
```

... although only `key` will be matched.  One solution, if you are sure that only the keyword will take up the rest of the line, would be to force only the whitelisted characters to appear up until the end of the line, like so:

```
/^#\s*([a-zA-Z\-\s]+)$/
```

Here's another option.  If you just want to make sure the first set of characters after your initial hash and whitespace doesn't contain an asterisk, you can use:

```
/^#\s*([a-zA-Z\-]+)(?:\s|$)/
```

This will match:

```
# keyword foo
```

And it will match:

```
# keyword
```

But it will not match:

```
# key*word foo
```

Nor:

```
# key*word
```

Nor:

```
# key* word foo
```

Nor:

```
# **** keyword
```

Comment: Not correct - I made the same mistake. It's because of the \s inside the character class.

Comment: My first regex captures a null value for my keyword. For some reason it matches "# **** keyword", and I want to specifically tell it to not match asterisk.
I'm probably explaining this very badly...

Comment: OK, it will match stuff *up to* an asterisk, but it won't match the asterisk itself.

Comment: Correct, I want it to ignore the entire string if it contains an asterisk.

Comment: I don't understand why you changed the ":" to a "!".  The expression tries to positively match a space character or the end of the line.

Comment: Oh.. I was wrong. But for some reason your script doesn't match anything.

Answer (score 1):

I take it the problem is that you match partially for strings with asterisk, like this:

```
foobar*  =>  matching string "foobar"
```

What you might try is using a negative lookahead assertion, like this:

```
/^#\s*(?!.*\*)(.+)/
```

This `.*\*` asserts that no asterisk appears anywhere in front of the pound sign. This is, however, just a fancy way of doing two things in one:

```
if (!/\*/ && /^#\s*(.+)/) { ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try matching using this regex:

```
^#\s*([-a-zA-Z]+)(?=\s|$)
```

Your regex already doesn't match `# *keyword`, but this regex removed the whitespace from the captured group and uses a look ahead to assert that the character following the word is not an asterisk, so it won't match `# key*word`.

Also note this slight simplification of not having to escape the dash when it's the first (or last) character in the character class.

See a [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/sqqSaFbwB9) of this on rubular.

Comment: @Jez I'm a "less code is good" kinda guy. To me, escape char = code noise, and I'm so familiar with this rule that to me not escaping is actually noticeably clearer (with the escape mentally I have to ignore the backslash, which I find more effort that just reading the dash)